# Problema con DataTable

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, datatables

Lo que sucede es que al refrescar la página crea un producto automáticamente (es el último producto que ingrese), es decir, está insertando al refrescar la página repetidamente, y el otro problema es que cuando ingreso recién el segundo producto, se muestra el primero en la tabla, es como si estuviera desfasado.

Envió el código Gracias!

addInsumos.blade.php
TABLA

```
<div class="panel-body" style="margin-top: 200px;">

                            <table class="table table-bordered" id="myTable">
                                <head>
                                    <th>Id</th>
                                    <th>Nombre</th>
                                    <th>Categoria</th>
                                    <th>fecha</th>
                                    <tbody>
                                        @foreach ($insumos as $insumos )
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{$insumos->id}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$insumos->nombre}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$insumos->categoria}}</td>
                                                <td>{{$insumos->created_at}}</td>
                                            </tr>
                                        @endforeach
                                    </tbody>
                                </head>
                            </table>
                        </div>
```

insumosController.php
CONTROLADOR

```
 function viewaddinsumo() 
    {
        //Ver la tabla
        $insumos = \App\insumos::latest('id')
                ->take(5)
                ->get();
        return view('Insumos/addInsumo',compact('insumos'));
    }//                                           _____
                                                 //WW||
    function sendforminsumo(Request $request)   //·.·||
    {      
            //insertar el producto o insumo 
            $insumos = \App\insumos::latest('id')->take(5)->get();
            $name = $request->input('nameP');
            $categoriaP = $request->get('categoriaP');


            DB::table('insumos')->insert(['nombre'=>$name, 'categoria'=>$categoriaP]);

            return view('Insumos/addInsumo',compact('insumos'));


    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estimado, creo que la solución a su consulta es la forma en como estabas guardando los elementos en tu **controlador**.

Recomiendo que utilices Eloquent, para simplificar tu código.

```
function sendforminsumo(Request $request)   
    {      
            //insertar el producto o insumo 
            $insumos = new insumos;

            $insumos->name = $request->input('nameP');

            $insumos->categoriaP = $request->get('categoriaP');

            $insumos->save();//guardas el insumo en tu base de datos

            return view('Insumos/addInsumo',compact('insumos'))->with('succes');

    }
```

Espero te sea de utilidad mi respuesta. 
Saludos

Edit: 
Añado ademas una documentación de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) y en especifico la de Eloquent, que te serán de mucha ayuda.
Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Lo intentare, gracias hector!

Comment: Si te funciona, dala como respuesta correcta para que le sirva a otras personas, saludos.

Comment: Funciona 10/10 jaja gracias!

Comment: Te recomiendo, como extra que le añadas buenas practicas a tus modelos y controladores, como por ejemplo cuando crees tu modelo, utiliza php artisan make:model InsumosController -cr, con esto crearas tus resources en el controlador, index, store, update, etc y además creara tu controlador.
Por otro lado al momento de utilizarlos en las rutas, solo deberas colocar Route::resources('insumos','InsumosController'); y podras tener todos los metodos del controlador generados previamente, te lo recomiendo. Saludos y recuerda darle un voto si la respuesta fue correcta.